# Proving details about a continued fraction sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

Let’s assume $a_n$ is a sequence of positive integers, and we have another sequence $A_n$ that
$$ A_1 = \frac{1}{a_1} $$
$$ A_2 = \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2}} $$
$$ ... $$

How should we prove that:

A) $A_n$ converges to an **irrational** number called $A$ **between 0 and 1**;

and

B) If $a_n$ is periodic, $A$ is a root of an quadratic equation like $mx^2 + nx + p = 0$ ($m$, $n$ and $p$ are positive integers)

Could we generalize the proof found to find a way to write irrational numbers (like $\sqrt{2}$) in continued fraction format?

Comment: Oh this is a fun one! I've been wondering about this very problem for a while, but I haven't gotten anywhere. Good luck, I'm going to be following this.

Comment: For (A) the answer is short; for (B) it’s long, and I’m too lazy. For (A) now, every rational has precisely two expansions, both of which terminate, one of them with $+\frac11$. No others. Thus if a continued-fraction expansion is infinite, the limit must be irrational. Two distinct numbers definitely have different expansions. You can prove this for yourself fairly easily, looking at the associated inequalities. I’ll leave it to someone else to attack (B). I should say that there seems to be no good way to expand other algebraic numbers than quadratic. (Others may correct me.)